# find the biggest change in a time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series in R

e.g.

```
[1]  0.2  0.6  0.4 -0.2 -0.1  0.3  0.8  0.7
```

How can I find out the biggest change in the series? (from point 4 to 7 biggest change =1)
How can I find out were a change of e.g. 1 is? (again from 4 (= -0.2) to 7 (= 0,8)

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the distance matrix for a set of points, you can use the `dist` function. After that it is just a matter of selecting the point pair with the highest distance between them. In code:

```
m = as.matrix(dist(runif(10)))
m == max(m)
       1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
1  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
6  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
7  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
8  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
9  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
10 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
which(m == max(m), arr.ind = TRUE)[1,]
row col 
 10   6
```

Comment: thanks for that fast answer, but i have a dataset of about 600000 points and I want to find the first point where there is a change of 1. So i am looking for the answer 7 in the example, because at point seven the first time a change of 1 can be noticed. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: I'd just iterate over the points, calculate the distance (e.g. euclidian), and break the loop once you have a match.

Comment: We all start as beginners, only using practice you learn to become better. A straightforward double for loop should suffice as a first approach. Alternatively, you can randomly sample your vector until you get what you want, .e.g using a combination of `runif`, and a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand.grid` here.

```
exg <- expand.grid(x, x)
exg[apply(exg, 1, diff) == VALUE.TO.FIND, ]  # notice the ', ' (comma-and-space)

  Var1 Var2
52 -0.2  0.8
```

*where `VALUE.TO.FIND` is whichever specific value you are seraching for*

---

If instead you want to find the maximum distance:

```
dist <- apply(exg, 1, diff)
exg[dist == max(dist),  ]
```

Comment: +1, although the OP probably wants to prevent calculating the entire distance matrix as an additional requirement (not in the question) that the vector is very large.

Answer (score 0):

To get the biggest change in a list, just iterate through it and get the max and min values. Then compare them. It's in O(n) time. It's dirt simple.

To find a certain change is a little more complex. Don't know why you'd want it, but it's still possible. One way would be to call the first function you just wrote with every combination of start index and end indexes of the list. That's a little more computationally complex, but it's the simplest way of implementing it. Then when you get the change from position 1 to 2, you can check to see if it's what you want, if not, 1-3. Eventually you'll get to n-1 to n, and if that's not the change you're looking for, then it's not in the set. 
This method will be in O(n^2).